# Invoke bat file from JavaScript file with parameters

Tags: batch-file, javascript, jquery

What I need to do is to pass two parameters from HTML to a batch file.
I am invoking a batch file from a JavaScript method inside HTML, and I am able to invoke the bat file, but I can't pass any parameter.

Did anyone came across this issue before?

Comment: isn't this more of a SO question? also, seems to be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994595/html-hyperlink-to-call-exe-with-parameters). Basically, it cannot be done.

Comment: @eis this is no more an SO question than any other one liner .bat or powershell question.

Comment: either or, it's anyway covered by the question in SO I linked.